# Ngnix - write: permission denied when transfering files with Filezilla to root directory

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, sftp, vps, filezilla

I am trying to transfer files with Filezilla to the root directory (/usr/share/nginx/www) of my nginx VPS via SFTP. The data-transfer fails with the following error-message:

```
/usr/share/nginx/www/test.php: open for write: permission denied
```

I am not using the root user, but created a user with sudo-rights to access my server.

I already tried to get `www-data` group permissions for my user with the following commands, however, without success:

```
sudo newgrp www-data

sudo usermod -a -G www-data myuser
```

Any idea how to get write permissions to transfer my files?

Comment: not sure how reliable this would be, but a fast fix is to run `sudo chmod -R 775 /usr/share/nginx/www/`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a very good idea, if you have a look at this [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/chmod-r-775-root-729646/).

Comment: the link is talking about the whole `/root`, I'm only talking about the `www` directory, this is the only way to make the file editable by your user, an other option is to change the nginx runner user from `www-data` to the same uploading user

Comment: I tried 'sudo chmod -R 775 /usr/share/nginx/www/', rebootet the machine and I still don't get permission to transfer files.

Comment: do you get `www-data` when you run the command `groups` as the same user who uploads?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following command finally gave me the required permissions:

```
sudo chown username /usr/share/nginx/www
```